# How to query the permissions of all installed Apps on an Android device?

Tags: android, android-permissions

my problem is like this:

I got like 200 Apps installed and made a list of them. Now I want to rate those Apps according to privacy.

All usual tools like F-Secure App Permissions or aSpotCat do help with that, but it's mostly manual labor, because their lists are not exportable. So I would have to transfer the information X_X

I was looking for Apps which could at least generate a list according to a query, but could not find one.

Basically I would like to do this: "which apps on my mobile have NetworkAccess and at least one other PrivacyRElevantPermission?" -> LIST -> EXCEL -> NICE!

My Mobile is not rooted and it shall stay this way. But I have ADB and an Eclipse setup for AndroidDEV. However, I would like to avoid programming an App by my self right now. Right now, I hope someone could say: "This is easy, just get this App or use this command via ADB or just ... " - if not, I guess using aSApotCat will be the easiest way for now.

Thank you guys!

Comment: Maybe try $ adb shell pm list permissions and then filter the output

Comment: Thanks! Already made an output for all permissions, which helps a lot - could you maybe add an examplary usage with permissions <GROUP>; I am having trouble to get this right `list permissions NETWORK` does not what i've would have expected. You can make it an Answer, i'll rate it up.

Comment: ok, I was dancing too early, it seems this list is incomplete or limited in some way, as it seem not to catch all apps and all their permissions

Comment: That's odd - I'm currently on the go, but I'll try it myself as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `adb pull /data/system/packages.xml` to get an XML file with a list of all the intalled apps with their permissions and assorted data. The names of the apps are not listed though, just the package name, but it's usually pretty obvious to guess which app that belongs to. You can then write a simple XML parser to filter out the ones you want to find. You can import this to an Excel spreadsheet if you like.

**Edit:** It seems that this file is does not have read permissions on some devices.

Comment: Thanks, this would probably help, but it works only for rooted devices, since it tries to access the data folder.

Comment: @Jook: I find (on my non-rooted Galaxy S2) that while the `/data` folder doesn't have read permissions, the `/data/system` folder does have read/execute permissions, and the `packages.xml` also has read permissions. I was able to do an `adb pull` on it successfully.

Comment: sorry, I am on an non-rooted Galaxy S3 and /data is empty or non accessible through any file-explorer on the device and adb throws permission denied, when I try to pull packages.xml

Comment: @Jook: In that case the only scripting alternative seems to be writing an Android app that uses system API to get this data.

Comment: seems that way, as the `list permissions` way did not put out a complete list.

Comment: @Jook: Yes, the `list permissions` command just lists all registered system and app defined permissions, not a list of permissions held by the applications.

Comment: Any way to check which permissions are granted and which are denied?